# Formulário inserindo duas vezes no banco (F5)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tenho um grande formulário que realiza `update` e `insert` em vários pontos quando submetido. Entretanto, se no intervalo de tempo desse processo o usuário pressionar F5, ele duplica o registro de inserção o número de vezes que ele apertar a tecla.

Utilizo: `PHP` com `CodeIgniter`, `MySQL` com `Lumine`.

Comment: Só no fim de submeteres o formulário e pressionares F5 é que duplica os dados? É que se for isso a questão não tem a haver com o teu código, mas sim pelo processo nativo dos browsers ao submeter um formulário.

Comment: Poderia nos mostrar o código SQL executado ao enviar o formulário?

Comment: Entendi Cesar Miguel. Em qualquer momento do processamento, se eu pressionar F5, os dados irão duplicar... :\

Comment: Infelizmente não Paulo. Mas seria um insert into comum de SQL.

Comment: Terminou a operação? foi realizada com sucesso? redirecione o usuário para uma página de sucesso e limpe o SESSION e CACHE se for o caso de usa-los

Comment: tente adicionar a propriedade autocomplete="off" ao elemento < form >

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Por padrão, o <kbd>F5</kbd> atualiza sua página, e se você acabou de enviar informações de formulário, ele normalmente pedirá uma confirmação:

[image: Captura de Tela]

É normal que se você clicar em reenviar seja enviado novamente as mesmas informações, é um comportamento nativo dos *browsers*.

Porém, você deve checar se há um registro com o mesmo `PrimaryKey` (normalmente o ID) e se houver você deve dar `UPDATE` ao invés de `INSERT`.

Comment: Entendi Paulo. Mas no caso, como realizar uma verificação dessa em um sistema imenso? Há algo que pode ser realizado no Framework?

Comment: SQL é SQL, PHP é PHP. São coisas diferentes, porém você pode fazer o seguinte, antes de qualquer coisa, com os dados do formulário em mãos, faça um `select` no banco com o id que o formulário está enviando, verifique se o ID já existe, caso já exista, de `UPDATE`, se não existir, utilize `INSERT`, porém você deve (ao carregar o formulário) utilizar um generator ou fazer um `max()` nos id's pra saber qual o maior deles, e somar +1, para que sempre que o usuário abra uma página nova de formulário esteja criando um novo registro ao inves de alterar.

Comment: Beleza Paulo... Na realidade precisa dinamizar o processo... Consegui realizar a sugestão do Bruno direto em meu Framework. Tudo ok. Muito obrigado! :-)

Comment: Muitíssimo Obrigado @Zuul ! Realmente a imagem é muito útil!

Answer (score 6):

Sugiro que você utilize um token e redirecione os usuários para outra página (302) após processar o formulário. Dessa forma os mesmos dados não serão enviados multiplas vezes ao pressionar F5.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' &&
   isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['token']) &&
   $_POST['token'] === $_SESSION['form_token']) {
   // Insert ...
   unset($_SESSION['form_token']);
   header('X-PHP-Response-Code: 302');
   header('Location: /index.php');
   return;
}
$token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
$_SESSION['form_token'] = $token;
?>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="field1">
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token ?>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Como desenvolvedor, você sempre deve pensar no pior cenário possível e sempre levar em conta a inexperiência (pra ser bonzinho) dos usuários.

Você pode ter algum JS que intermeie alguma ação de repetição daquela requisição (F5, por exemplo), mas você também deve considerar aquele usuário que realmente tem algum conhecimento no assunto e, por exemplo, navega com o mínimo de JS habilitado (como eu) o que potencialmente anularia sua suposta "proteção".

E é nesse ponto que entra a verificação do lado servidor. Você tem duas opções e ambas podem ser implementadas em paralelo:

- Aceitar múltiplas inserções, mas permitir ao usuário visualizar as transações efetuadas e, se for o caso, remover alguma duplicidade por conta própria, como num Carrinho de Compras que tem uma visão geral dos pedidos antes de efetuar a compra.
- Distinguir se uma requisição é um novo envio ou um recarregamento armazenando em uma *session* um hash de todas as informações do formulário e só inserir de fato caso seja **realmente** uma submissão.

Essa segunda alternativa é bem simples, basta armazenar na sessão um hash MD5 de tudo o que se tem no formulário:

```
<?php

session_start();

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) {

    $hash = md5( implode( $_POST ) );

    if( isset( $_SESSION['hash'] ) && $_SESSION['hash'] == $hash ) {

        // Refresh! Não faz nada ou re-exibe o formulário preenchido

    } else {

        $_SESSION['hash']  = $request;

        // Submissão legítima! Insere ;)
    }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="field" value="value" />
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Bruno. Fiz um pouco diferente mas sob este mesmo conceito. Valeu! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção é vc redirecionar o usuário para uma outra página diferente da que vc usa para  "salvar" o formulário, vc pode fazer isso com [header](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php).

```
header("Location: http://www.seusite.com.br/cadastroEfetuado.php");
```

Essa nova página não terá como reenviar o formulário novamente.

Como dica: crie uma arquivo do tipo `salvaForm.php` esse arquivo só processa o `form` e envia para uma outra página.