# Executar código PHP uma só vez

Tags: php

Quero que o código seja executado apenas uma vez, porque sempre que faço refresh volta a inserir na base de dados sqlite. Sem executar a partir de um botão. 
código:

```
if(!file_exists($dir.$base)) {  
$base_hndl  =   new SQLite3($dir.$base);
$requete = "CREATE TABLE 'contact' (
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
nom TEXT NULL,
prenom TEXT NULL,
categorie TEXT NULL
)";             
$result = $base_hndl->exec($requete);} else {
$row = 0;
$delemiter = ";" ;

$data = array();

    if (($handle = fopen("contacts.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2000, $delemiter)) !== FALSE)
        { 
            $num = count($data);
            $row++;
            $base_hndl  =   new SQLite3($dir.$base);
            $query_value = "";
            $query = "INSERT INTO contact (nom,prenom,categorie) VALUES ( ";

            for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) 
            {

                if($data[$c] == "")
                { 
                    $query_value .= "\"0\"";
                }
                else
                {
                    //$query .= "'" . $data[$c] . "'";
                    $query_value .= "\"$data[$c]\"";
                }
                if ($c+1 < $num) 
                {
                   $query_value .= ",";
                }
            }
            $query_value .= ")\n";

            $result = $base_hndl->exec($query.$query_value);    
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

}
```

Comment: Pode criar uma tabela que só registre o dia da importação caso já exista essa data não importa. Pode colocar o campo data como `unique key` ou seja nenhuhm valor da coluna data poderá se repetir.

Comment: Ja tentou usar sessão? assim só executa o código quando fecha e abre o browser novamente

Comment: session_start();?

Comment: [Isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5417/250) pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

Basta que antes do código de inserção verifiques se foi feito POST, ou seja, se foi através de *submit*:

```
if (filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
{
    //código de inserção após clicar no botão
}
```

Comment: Certo, mas não tenho nenhum butao submit. Le do ficheiro e insere quando é carregada a página

Comment: Edita a tua pergunta que não percebi assim. Tu queres que esse código execute uma vez e nunca mais execute?

Comment: Sim porque é carregado apenas um ficheiro, e mostra.

Comment: Não estou a compreender.

Comment: executar o código uma vez.

Answer (score -1):

Não entendi, se deseja quer o código seja executado apenas uma vez, então faça com oque a página seja executada apenas uma vez também

@Edit
Faça um select e depois if para verificar se o registro já existe, se já existir não insere, se não existir insere.

```
if($registro > 0){
// não faz nada
}else{
//aqui vai o código se inserção
}
```

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele - você sempre pode comentar em suas próprias publicações e quando tiver [pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes você poderá [comentar sobre qualquer publicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Fiz um edit na minha resposta

Answer (score -3):

Faz um SELECT antes do INSERT para saber se já existe o registro que está sendo inserido a cada atualização da página.

Comment: Sem dúvida você deseja ajudar, mas uma sugestão é elaborar um pouco mais a resposta como por adicionar um exemplo. Visite o [tour] para conhecer como o site funciona e veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer