# Actualizar página sem voltar a executar o código PHP

Tags: php

Quero executar um código PHP com o botão **submit**. O problema é que sempre que actualizo a página, o código volta a ser executado. Utilizei isto:

```
  if (isset($_POST['carregar'])) {
      // pedaço de código...
  }
```

E o botão:

```
echo "<form method=POST action=#>";
echo "<input type=submit name=carregar value=Carregar>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: e qual é o problema?

Comment: Sempre que atualizo a página, volta a executar o codigo, mesmo sem clicar no butão.

Comment: Tens de fazer como eu te disse nesta resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40158/7210

Comment: Certo e como identifico o nome do botão?

Comment: fazes `if(isset($_POST['carregar']))` dentro do `if` daquela resposta.

Comment: if (filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
 {
  if(isset($_POST['carregar'])){

Comment: Ainda continua com o problema, @akm?

Comment: Se eu fosse você, começaria a pensar no uso do [**Ajax**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax?sort=votes&pageSize=15)

Answer (score 0):

Como referido [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40158/7210) é só verificar qual o botão acionado:

```
// Verifica se foi feito um POST
if (filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
{
    // Verifica se o foi com o botão carregar
    if(isset($_POST['carregar']))
    {
        //código de inserção após clicar no botão
    }
}
```

Comment: Fiz isso, e continua a executar quando actualizo a pagina.

Comment: Não pode... Eu estive aqui a testar e não acontece isso.

Comment: O melhor será mesmo verificar na Base de Dados se esse registo já existe. Se existir não adiciona. Como nesta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40169/7210