# Como não permitir INSERT repetido dando reload na página?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

De que forma posso fazer para não permitir realizar `INSERT` repetido se alguém fizer um reload na página?

Exemplo:

```
$libera = $_POST['libera'];

if ($libera == "sim"){
    $sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO a_finan(id_reserva,id_cliente)VALUES('$id_res','$id_cliente')", $conexao) or die( mysql_error());
}else{
    echo"";
}
```

Se eu dou um `submit` para executar esse código, após ele ser executado, se der um reload na página ele executa de novo. Como evitar isso?

Comment: Talvez seja duplicata de [Formulário inserindo duas vezes no banco F5](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5406/91)

Comment: Com certeza, uma duplicata. As 3 respostas lá são praticamente idênticas ao que postamos aqui. Engraçado que a resposta do @Bruno Augusto mostra como fazer com session, o mesmo que eu mostrei aqui. Mas lá não tem negativo. rsrs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode  verificar se já existe estes valores.

Por exemplo:

```
<?

$libera = $_POST['libera']; 
if ($libera == "sim"){

// MODIFICAÇÃO

$sqlChecar = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM a_finan WHERE id_reserva = '$id_res' AND id_cliente = '$id_cliente'");
// Irá buscar os registros

if(mysql_num_rows($sqlChecar) === 0){
// Se não houver resgistros faça...

// FIM DA MODIFICAÇÃO 

$sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO a_finan(id_reserva,id_cliente)VALUES('$id_res','$id_cliente')", $conexao) or die( mysql_error());
// Insere normalmente

}else{
//se não

echo "Já existe";


}
}else{
echo ""
}
```

Desta forma irá verificar, antes de inserir, se já existe um registro com os mesmos valores.

> O mysql_* já está obsoleto e não recomendo, se  estiver no inicio do desenvolvimento (ou está apenas apredendo) experimente usar o mysqli. 
>   Lembre-se que nenhum tipo de recurso de segurança foi utilizado!

Comment: mysqli_* ou PDO tb.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe PDO complicaria à toa. E o mysqli além de tudo tem binding real de parâmetros, o PDO só simula. A única situação que eu consigo imaginar pra usar o PDO no lugar do mysqli é se o autor precisar que a aplicação funcione em vários bancos diferentes (mas isso é raro).

Comment: Acredito que a vantagem do PDO é suportar outros bancos  além do MySQL. Não é solução inválida porque também suporta, mas sua vantagem, neste caso, não é útil. Por isso sugerir o mysqli_*

Answer (score 5):

Como o @Inkeliz disse, você pode verificar se o registro já existe antes de inserir.

Outra coisa que eu faço e recomendo é: após uma inserção, redirecionar para a listagem daquilo que foi inserido, por exemplo, se foi inserido um produto, então redirecione para a listagem de produtos, assim se o usuário recarregar a página ele irá recarregar a listagem e não a inserção.

**Para redirecionar em PHP** (adicionado `exit` por sugestão do @bacco)

```
header('Location: destino.php'); 
exit; // para garantir que o script termine aqui
```

Comment: +1!  Redirect é minha solução preferida.

Comment: Conteúdo sobre o assunto, [Understanding “post/redirect/get”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10827242/1342547) 
[Aplicando Post/Redirect/Get Pattern na prática com PHP](
http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/php/aplicando-postredirectget-pattern-na-pratica-com-php/?trace=1519021197&source=single) e [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: Nesse caso acredito qeu seria melhor adicionar o header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");, porque o usuário poderia voltar o URL anterior, alguns navegadores exibem "deseja reenviar"  por exemplo. Se utilizar o 301 geralmente o navegador salva em cache o redirecionamento, tendendo a redirecionar sempre que entrar ou tentar reenviar, mas também não é certo. Acredito que por via das duvidas fazer ambas as soluções seria o ideal.

Answer (score 3):

O mais simples é redirecionar para uma outra página, contudo, o usuário ainda poderá voltar a página e reprocessá-la.

Para prover uma maior garantia, levante uma flag usando variável de sessão:

```
if ($libera == "sim" && !isset($_SESSION['submitted'])){
    $sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO a_finan(id_reserva,id_cliente)VALUES('$id_res','$id_cliente')", $conexao) or die( mysql_error());

    $_SESSION['submitted'] = true;
}else{
    echo "";
}
```

Na página do formulário, coloque:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['submitted'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['submitted']);
}
```

Isso serve para resetar a flag e poder postar legitimamente a partir do formulário caso o usuário queira cadastrar alguma outra coisa, não duplicada.

**Iniciando a sessão**

Obviamente, deve saber que para o uso de variáveis de sessão é preciso inicializá-las com [session_start()](http://php.net/session_start).

Omiti a inicialização nos exemplos acima pois pode ser que o seu sistema já esteja usando e isso poderia provocar algum erro. Caso os seus scripts não estejam usando, basta invocar a função:

No formulário:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['submitted'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['submitted']);
}
```

No script que recebe os dados e grava:

```
session_start();
if ($libera == "sim" && !isset($_SESSION['submitted'])){
    $sql = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO a_finan(id_reserva,id_cliente)VALUES('$id_res','$id_cliente')", $conexao) or die( mysql_error());

    $_SESSION['submitted'] = true;
}else{
    echo "";
}
```

**Vamos complicar o assunto?**

O usuário ainda poderá fazer um backward e um forward (retonar e avançar) pelo histórico de navegação. Aí nesse caso, o usuário está de sacanagem. Mas pode ser algo legítimo. É possível implementar mais reforço nesses casos usando a variável de sessão, por exemplo, verificando se os dados enviados são exatamente os mesmos já enviados anteriormente.

**Vantagem de uso**

Não é o caso da pergunta aqui mas, para casos onde não há um controle da chave primária a ser inserido, não seria viável usar a técnica de buscar no banco de dados antes de inserir pois, sem uma chave única, tornaria a query de busca mais complexa e muitas vezes inexata.

Exemplo de situação: uma tabela com chave primária do tipo autoincrement.

A técnica com sessão também ajuda a prevenir ações de bots e spammers pois uma sessão deve ser iniciada na página original do formulário. Não quer dizer que seja 100% seguro contra bots ou spammers, porém, ajuda a a dificultar tais ações.

**Notas adicionais**

Uma variável de sessão expira, mas ainda assim melhor do que não ter nada. Além do mais uma sessão pode ser configurada para expirar num tempo maior do que 1 hora. Um dia por exemplo. Para ter um reforço ainda maior, pode usar `$_COOKIE`, ao invés de session. Então vamos ouvir que o usuário pode excluir o cookie. Ok, mas aí deixa de ser um usuário comum e fica claro a má intensão. Para usuário desse tipo, pode colocar o bloqueio que for que encontrará meio de burlar. Nesses casos é bom precaver-se contra atividades suspeitas e tomar as medidades cabíveis. Nesse ponto entramos numa discussão paralela, o que não convém adicionar aqui pois desviaria muito do foco principal, ramificando para assuntos diversos.

Comment: Não entendi o negativo. Quem votou poderia explicar onde viu motivo para tal..

Comment: Não fui eu que votei negativo! Mas o SESSION pode expirar, caso o usuário mantenha a página aberta por muito tempo e depois retorne-a pode inserir novamente.

Comment: Uma variável de sessão expira, mas ainda assim melhor do que não ter nada. Além do mais uma sessão pode expirar num tempo maior do que 1 hora. Um dia por exemplo.

Comment: adicionei na resposta esse assunto que comentaste, @Inkeliz, tal como outras observações óbvias.