# Problemas ao fazer uma requisição ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou com um problema de requisição

quando clico no botão salvar ele faz 1 requisição ou seja salva 1 vez no banco se clicar novamente ele faz 2 de uma só vez salvando 2 vezes no banco clicando novamente ele faz 3 de uma só vez salvando 3 vezes no banco de dados.

preciso ter 1 por clique.

segue código

html

```
<form id="form" class="" action="javascript:;" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" method="post">

<button class="btn btn-primary" name="" onclick="sub('achadoPerdido','Incluir')">Salvar</button>
```

javascript

```
function sub(arquivo, acao) {
    $("#form").submit(function (e) {
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        formData.append("acao", acao);
        formData.append("arquivo", arquivo);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            url: 'model/acao/controller.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }).done(function (html) {
            console.log(html);

        });

    });
}
```

Comment: [Formulário inserindo duas vezes no banco F5](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5406/91)

Comment: Você quer aguardar terminar a primeira requisição pro usuário poder salvar novamente?

Comment: @rray não é isso estou fazendo com ajax se atualizar a pagina não pode acontecer nada a não ser limpar o formulario

Comment: @Laerte O problema é que ele está salvando mais de uma vez no banco com um unico clique no botão conforme descrito no problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toda vez que você da um clique no seu botão chama a função `sub` (`onclick="sub('achadoPerdido','Incluir')"`), esta por sua vez cria um listener para o evento submit no elemento `#form` (`*$("#form").submit(function (e) {...`), ou seja, cada clique no botão vai gerar um novo listener que vai ficar acumulado. Para resolver você tem duas opções:

1. Remova do botão salvar o `onclick="sub('achadoPerdido','Incluir')"` e invoque a função `sub` manualmente no seu js com `sub('achadoPerdido','Incluir')` (apenas uma vez), de preferência dentro de um `$(document).ready(...`
2. Remova o listener `$("#form").submit(function (e) {` da função `sub`, ele não é necessário da maneira como você está usando ela, também substítua o `new FormData($(this)[0]);` por algo como `new FormData( $("#form")[0]);`.

Answer (score 1):

O `async: false` não funciona com o `.done()`, você deve usar ele de modo assíncrono, o `async: false` logo será descontinuado, como eu expliquei aqui:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117483/3635

Remova isso:

```
async: false,
cache: false,
```

Me parece que você não entendeu bem o uso de cada um, recomendo que leia a documentação antes: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Após ler a outra resposta entendi melhor o que ocorre, exatamente o foi dito, ao executar `sub` são adicionado vários eventos `.submit` ao form (pra cada clique), o melhor talvez é seria descartar o form e deixar apenas o Ajax, deve ficar assim:

```
function sub(arquivo, acao) {
    var Self = this;

    if (Self.working) {
         return;
    }

    Self.working = true;

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    formData.append("acao", acao);
    formData.append("arquivo", arquivo);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        url: 'model/acao/controller.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).done(function (html) {
        console.log(html);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }).complete(function() {
        Self.working = false;
    });
}
```

> Sempre use o `.fail` pra verificar quando houver erro de servidor, conexão ou parseamento do Json ou Xml.

Também adicionei o `this.working`, se `true` ele impede o duplo clique até que termine o processo, se `false` é por que já está completo e pode executar novamente.

O HTML pode ficar apenas o `button` já que o processo é todo pelo ajax agora:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sub('achadoPerdido','Incluir')">Salvar</button>
```

Comment: remevi os que falou, mas não está entrando dentro do DONE ele chega nele é pula para o complete

Comment: eu já tinha removido o async coloquei um alert dentro do done e não mostrou, depurei o js e não entra dentro do done.  vou dar um control c no seu codigo e ver.

Comment: jquery-1.11.0.min

Comment: @Herick acho que é um problema no teu back-end vou adicionar um exemplo pra ajudar a depurar, pode ser um erro de parse no Json

Comment: O problema era o back-end mesmo resolvi aqui. Obrigado.

Comment: @Herick postei um novo código, veja se ajuda ;)